# Calculate distance with MKGeodesicPolyline Swift 3 will end up in an error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-location, xcode8

I try to create a `MKGeodesicPolyline` between two coordinates:

```
let LAX = CLLocation(latitude: 33.9424955, longitude: -118.4080684)
let JFK = CLLocation(latitude: 40.6397511, longitude: -73.7789256)

var coordinates = [LAX.coordinate, JFK.coordinate]
let geodesicPolyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: 2)

mapView.addOverlay(geodesicPolyline)
```

Unfortunately, it will trow me an error:

```
Ambiguous use of 'init(coordinates:count:)'
```

Already search for this problem, but can't find a working solution within Swift 3 / Xcode 8.

Anyone suggestions or the solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove `&` and it will compile:

```
let geodesicPolyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: 2)
```

Comment: Hm interesting, it says `UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>` in the documentation.

Comment: It is working. Wow. Strange, because I already try that without the `&` and also `&coordinates[0]` and also `coordinates[0]`.. Interesting.

Comment: Check what Xcode displays as reference. There may be a bug in the Apple documentation, and it's worth opening a bug report for it.